# Ending a loop properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm stuck on this code I'm trying to complete. I want it to print "there's no more recipes left", but it prints "lets choose a different meal" twice.

```
my_choice = ["a","b","c"]
bank = {"recipe1":[["a","b","c"], "d", "e", "f"],
        "recipe2":[["a","b","c"], "g", "h", "i"],
        "recipe3":[["a","b","c"], "j", "k", "l"],
        "recipe4":["x", "y", "z"]}

for k,v in bank.items():
    if my_choice in v:
        print(f"Your meal we have chosen for you is {k,v}")
        print("Do you like your meal? y/n")
        choice = input()
    if choice == "y":
        print("Enjoy your meal!")
        break
    elif choice == "n":
        print("Lets find you a different meal") # this prints out twice when the alternate recipes run out.
    else:
        print("Please select y or n to keep your meal or select a different recipe.")
        print(f"Your meal we have chosen for you is {k,v}")
        print("Do you like your meal? y/n")
        choice = input()

        if len(my_choice) in food_bank.items() > len(v):
            print("Sorry we have no more recipes")
```

Comment: Thanks I actually quite like this solution. The only thisnis once it doesn’t find any more variations of my_choice it produces the next alternative recipe which is recipe4. Is there any way I could print ‘let’s try something different’ before an alternate recipe from my_choice is given?

Comment: I like the use of the lambda, I had to research it a bit more I will try to understand them a bit more as I feel they could be really useful for future development. Thanks for the both solutions from both parties it gives me another way of looking at things and want to get into learning python more ! Any help you give is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

First, the `if choice == "y"` and `elif choice == "n"` statement should inside `if my_choice in v:`

Second, when `elif choice == "n"` you need to know if that is the last recipe (i.e. 'recipe4').

```
my_choice = ["a","b","c"]
bank = {"recipe1":[["a","b","c"], "d", "e", "f"],
        "recipe2":[["a","b","c"], "g", "h", "i"],
        "recipe3":[["a","b","c"], "j", "k", "l"],
        "recipe4":["x", "y", "z"]}

for k,v in bank.items():
    if my_choice in v:
        print(f"Your meal we have chosen for you is {k,v}")
        print("Do you like your meal? y/n")
        choice = input()
        if choice == "y":
            print("Enjoy your meal!")
            break
        elif choice == "n":
            if "recipe4" != "recipe4":
                print("Lets find you a different meal") # this prints out twice when the alternate recipes run out.
            else:
                print("Sorry we have no more recipes")
        else:
            print("Please select y or n to keep your meal or select a different recipe.")
            print(f"Your meal we have chosen for you is {k,v}")
            print("Do you like your meal? y/n")
            choice = input()
```

Comment: It looks like I would need to know each position of the recipe and which recipe is after which in the ‘bank’ object. Ideally the ‘bank’ would house 100’s or 1000’s of recipes, so basically  I would need to put the next recipe along the list which is NOT a match of my_choice - which would tell the code to stop ..correct? thanks for your help :)

Comment: @SinclairAkoto correct. So it is better to use while loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter ’n’ repeatedly, then once the loop gets to 'recipe4', which does not contain 'my_choice'/'["a","b","c"], then a new value is not set for 'choice'. So it sees ’n’ from last time, and prints the different meal text the second time.

Here's what I suggest for your code.

```
my_choice = ["a","b","c"]
bank = {"recipe1":[["a","b","c"], "d", "e", "f"],
        "recipe2":[["a","b","c"], "g", "h", "i"],
        "recipe3":[["a","b","c"], "j", "k", "l"],
        "recipe4":["x", "y", "z"]}

# Create a list from your dictionary
bankList = list(bank.items())
# And then sort it according to whether 'my_choice' is in a given recipe
# This way, the later loop will go through the matching recipes first
bankList.sort(key=lambda recipe: my_choice in recipe[1], reverse=True)

choice = None
for k, v in bank.items():
    if choice == "n":
        print("Let's find you a different meal")
    print(f"The meal we have chosen for you is {k,v}")
    print("Do you like your meal? y/n")
    choice = input()

    # If the user did not enter 'y' or 'n', keep asking until they do
    while choice not in ["y", "n"]:
        print("Please select y or n to keep your meal or select a different recipe.")
        print(f"The meal we have chosen for you is {k,v}")
        print("Do you like your meal? y/n")
        choice = input()

    if choice == "y":
        print("Enjoy your meal!")
        break
else:
    # This code will only run if the loop completes without breaking
    # In other words, if all recipes are considered and the user never says 'y' to any of them
    print("Sorry, we have no more recipes")
```